# Difference between Data transfer cost and Bandwidth costs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, bandwidth, data-transfer, billing

What is the difference between Data transfer costs and Bandwidth costs in AWS??

When I view my AWS bills, I see there are 2 types of expenses in Data Transfers tab, one of Data Transfer and one on Bandwidth costs. I tried to search a lot on this but could not get a clear demarcation on the difference between the two.

[image: Billing extract]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the bill that mentions Bandwidth? With which service was it associated?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : Please see the bill in the link that shows Data Transfer as well as Bandwidth costs. It is included under Data Transfer tab in the bill


[Bandwidth Cost](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xzfdj6owd9ebft/AWS_Bill_Screenshot.png?dl=0)

Comment: What does this have to do with computer programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to AWS support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that *is* confusing!

The top **Data Transfer** part seems to be data transfer between regions. From the [Amazon EC2 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/):

> - Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Another AWS Region = $0.02 per GB

The bottom **Bandwidth** part seems to be what is normally called Data Transfer (and the line items even use that wording).

> - Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Amazon EC2 Using a public or Elastic IP address = $0.01 per GB
> - Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet = $0.09 per GB

So, I guess "Data Transfer" is *between regions*, while Bandwidth is *out to the Internet*.

Comment: I suppose the data transfer between regions is via the Internet. Then why is there a demarcation between data transfer between regions and data transfer over the Internet?

Comment: There is a different charge for data transfer between regions and data transfer OUT to the Internet.

Comment: Ok @JohnRotenstein : The answer is quite satisfactory. It suffices my doubts. Am accepting your answer on stackoverflow