# Can you explain AWS billing rates on data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To design a system I need to decide on where to deploy the instances (suppose that I don't really care where they are but only want to optimize costs).

The [on-demand page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) mentions several billing items:

1. Data Transfer IN To Amazon EC2 From Internet
2. Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet
3. Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To (a list of regions)
4. Data Transfer Across AZ within this Region

My questions:

- About item 1 - they say this is free, is it? does it make sense that from Internet to Amazon is free while from Amazon to Amazon is not free? (I'm talking on the inbound data here, not the outbound).
- In items 2-3: does "Amazon" refer to all AWS services, including another EC2 instance?
- Regarding item 4: it is written `"Data transferred "in" to and "out" of Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift , Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX), and Amazon ElastiCache instances or Elastic Network Interfaces across VPC peering connections in the same AWS region is charged at $0.01/GB."` Is that meaning that if I run a process between 2 EC2 instances on the same region then I pay for each GB twice? first for outbound from one instance and second for the inbound on the other instance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't AWS support

Comment: reason I posted here is that I found other question on this topic on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149584/difference-between-data-transfer-cost-and-bandwidth-costs-in-aws and more

Comment: There are numerous articles and even training classes for understanding AWS pricing. I recommend "studying" those instead of asking for opinions.

Comment: There are numerous articles and even training classes for understanding almost everything discussed on this website. I didn't ask for an opinion.

Comment: But opinion is all you will get here. You need an authoritative and enforceable answer. Your linked question is also off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple rules-of-thumb are:

- **Inbound** traffic from the Internet to the AWS Cloud is **free**.
- **Outbound** traffic from the AWS Cloud to the Internet is charged at the applicable rates in each region (this is the majority of the cost). This applies to *anything* that sends traffic out to the Internet from your AWS services.
- Outbound traffic from the AWS Cloud to **Amazon CloudFront** has a lesser rate
- Traffic within a region but **between Availability Zones** is 1c/GB **in each direction**. In fact, the wording on the [EC2 Instance Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) page now shows this.

To answer your specific questions:

- Inbound is free
- Outbound is for *any AWS service* that sends traffic to the Internet
- Traffic between AZs or via VPC Peering is charged in "each direction"

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify on the 3rd question: If 2 instances send 1GB to one another then my overall cost would be COST_PER_GB times 4? or times 2?

Comment: From my reading, it would seem that if an instance in AZ-1 sends 1GB to an instance in AZ-2, then you would be charged 1GB _out_ and 1GB _in_, for a total of 2c. If the instance sent an equivalent amount back, it would be 4c. (2GB in + 2GB out.)